# R Change smallest value in group based on condition

Tags: r, group-by

I would like to know how to change the smallest non-zero value in group if the count of a condition in the group is 1.

For example, given the data frame:

```
df1 <- data.frame(x = unlist(map(letters[1:3], function(i) rep(i,4))),
                  y = rep('var',12),
                  z = c(c(10,0,'x',40), c(1,2,3,6),c(1,'x','x',6)))

df1

   x   y  z
1  a var 10
2  a var  0
3  a var  x
4  a var 40
5  b var  1
6  b var  2
7  b var  3
8  b var  6
9  c var  1
10 c var  x
11 c var  x
12 c var  6
```

I would like `a[1,3]` to change to `x` as there is only one "x" in the group a from col x, and the 10 is the smallest non-zero value in that group as to obtain the data frame:

```
  x   y  z
1  a var  x
2  a var  0
3  a var  x
4  a var 40
5  b var  1
6  b var  2
7  b var  3
8  b var  6
9  c var  1
10 c var  x
11 c var  x
12 c var  6
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

We group by 'x', create a `if/else` condition by checking the count of 'x' values in 'z', if the count is 1, then `replace` the values in 'z' where the 'z' value is equal to the `min` of the numeric values (after the 0 is converted to `NA` - `na_if`) to 'x'

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df1 %>% 
   group_by(x) %>% 
   mutate(z = if(sum(z == 'x') == 1) replace(z, 
       z == min(as.numeric(str_subset(na_if(z, '0'), '^[0-9.]+$')),
           na.rm = TRUE), 'x') else z) %>% 
   ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 12 × 3
   x     y     z    
   <chr> <chr> <chr>
 1 a     var   x    
 2 a     var   0    
 3 a     var   x    
 4 a     var   40   
 5 b     var   1    
 6 b     var   2    
 7 b     var   3    
 8 b     var   6    
 9 c     var   1    
10 c     var   x    
11 c     var   x    
12 c     var   6
```

Answer (score 2):

I think akruns solution is better, but just as an idea and because I like data.table more than dplyr:

```
library(data.table)
df1 = data.table(df1)

for (i in unique(df1$x)) {
  if (length(df1[x==i & z=="x", z]) == 1){
    df1[x==i & z==min(df1[x==i & z!=0, z]), z:="x"]
  }
}
```

And the output:

```
 > df1
    x   y  z
 1: a var  x
 2: a var  0
 3: a var  x
 4: a var 40
 5: b var  1
 6: b var  2
 7: b var  3
 8: b var  6
 9: c var  1
10: c var  x
11: c var  x
12: c var  6
```